# remove unwanted path

Tags: 7

I have tried a lot to **remove path** that you can see in below picture:

[image]

I am **new** to drupal and **learning** it.So right now I am converting **HTML template** in to **Drupal theme**.

So for that I have copied `bartik` folder and I am changing in that.

For the content, I have used an **article** and from **configuration** I have set that article on front and removed title using function in template.php.

But I am not able to find, **from where** that path is coming from.

Inspect element of that specific part :
[image]

My [`page--front.tpl.php`](http://paste.ofcode.org/MjqVr2JAp8R4giXPwWwWm5) and [`template.php`](http://paste.ofcode.org/39EXmFYb2znUB48XpdCejr5).

Ask me if more code is needed.

I have also tried by clearing cache but it did not help me out.

Comment: That path is showing under `node-1` ID.So does it mean that it should be in the editor of that node ? Cz I have checked in editor as well but there is no content like this.

Comment: since it's not in either of those two file you linked, try node.tpl.php

Comment: failing that, see if you have a block defined to show in the content area, or content-top, etc.

Comment: Yupp.. nice call ..Solved finally :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since it's not in either of those two file you linked, try node.tpl.php

failing that, see if you have a block defined to show in the content area, or content-top, etc.